# saving figures seaborn to sageplot

Tags: latex, integration, seaborn, sage

I have been trying to save statistical graphs (boxplot, barchart, histogram etc) of some random data generated using `Seaborn` into `LaTeX` without saving them into a file first. I use `\sageplot[width=8cm][png]{(Python_Graphics_Format)}` from `SageTex` package to do this.

For example, when I draw a Box Plot using `Seaborn` it generates all kinds of format (`name.gcf(), name.show(), name.plot(), name.draw()` etc) but Graphics format. Is there any way to do this without using 'name.savefig()' or likes?

Why is it important for me?

I would like to generate a list of predefined sage functions in a separate tex file together with bunch of randomly generated data and input them on top of my `TeX` code after `\maketitle`. This way, I will be able to generate multiple problems of similar nature and upload them to the online HW system `Ximera`.

Here is a code that I took from stackoverflow:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
```

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: This is really more of a matplotlib question than a seaborn question.

Comment: yes indeed! I tried to do it in `matplotlib` first but it did not work. Here is an alternative Q: Can I actually define a function that accepts a string `my_string` as an argument and later use it in `.savefig(''my_string.png'')`?